# Applying multiple transformations to the same variable?

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption

When a certain transformation is applied to a variable and the aim of that transformation is not met (e.g. normality, variance stabilization), can one apply several layers and/or types of transformations to the same variable to reach the aim? E.g. a log transformation of an already log transformed variable, or a log transformation of an already square root transformed variable etc.

Comment: As long as you can interpret your results there is no limit on what you can do.

Comment: Do you know where I can find something written on this issue? With regards to interpretation, can I go backwards in the transformation again to read out the results in the initial scale?